# How to write an inequality in R

Tags: r, inequalities

Sorry, I am an R newbie and I am having some difficulty

How would I write the following inequality in R:

x > 10 is twice more likely than x < 10

I tried this function and it didn't work :

```
X = 10 

f = function(X,Y) { 
  if ((2(X) >= 10 & X <= 10) { 
    print("in range") 
  } else {
    print("out of range") 
  } 
}
```

Comment: X = 10
    f = function(X,Y) {
    if ((2(X) >= 10 & X <= 10) {
    print("in range")
    }else{
    print("out of range")
    }
    }

Comment: You may [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66507782/edit) questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: `probX <- function(x){ifelse(x>10, 2/3, 1/3)}`

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a syntax error if that's the problem :

```
X = 10 
f = function(X,Y) {
  if (2 * X  >= 10 && X <= 10) {  # * instead of (
    print("in range") 
  } else { 
    print("out of range") 
  } 
}
```

You can try your function as in :

> ```
> > f(10,10)
> [1] "in range"
> > f(20,10)
> [1] "out of range"
> ```

Comment: Thank you. Will try now.